# How to convert a React class component to a function component with hooks to get firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have a working React class component that I want to convert to a functional component to use hooks for state etc. I am learning React hooks. The class component version works fine, the functional component is where I need help.

The data structure consists of a client list with three "clients". An image of it is here:

[image]

All I am trying to do is get this data, iterate over it and display the data of each name key to the user. Simple enough.

The problem is that a call to firebase from my component leads to erratic behavior in that the data is not retrieved correctly. The last client name is continuously called and it freezes up the browser. :)

Here is an image of the result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component,useContext,useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {Consumer,Context} from '../../PageComponents/Context';


const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
});


const FetchData = (props) =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState(["hi there"]);
    const userID = useContext(Context).userID;

    useEffect(() => {
        let clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
        clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
            const client = snapshot.val();
            client.key = snapshot.key;
            setState([...state, client])
         });
    });

    //____________________________________________________BEGIN NOTE: I am emulating this code from my class component and trying to integrate it

    // this.clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    //     const client = snapshot.val();
    //     client.key = snapshot.key;
    //     this.setState({ clients: [...this.state.clients, client]})
    //  });

    //___________________________________________________END NOTE


     console.log(state)

        return (

            <ul>

                {
                    state.map((val,index)=>{

                        return <a key={index} > <li>{val.name}</li>   </a>

                    }) 
                }

            </ul>
        )


}  


FetchData.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FetchData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that by default, `useEffect()` will run every single time your component renders. What is happening, is that your effect triggers a change in the component, which will trigger the effect running again and you end up with something approximating an endless loop.

Luckily react gives us some control over when to run the effect hook in the form of an array you can pass in as an additional parameter. In your case for example:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
        clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
            const client = snapshot.val();
            client.key = snapshot.key;
            setState([...state, client])
         });
    }, []);//An empty array here means  this will run only once.
```

The array tells react which properties to watch. Whenever one of those properties changes it will run the cleanup function and re-run the effect. If you submit an empty array, then it will only run once (since there are no properties to watch).  For example, if you were to add `[userId]` the effect would run every  time the `userId` variable changes.

Speaking of cleanup function, you are not returning one in your effect hook. I'm not familiar enough with firebase to know if you need to clean anything up when the component is destroyed (like for example remove the 'child_added' event binding).  It would be good practice to return a method as the last part of your use effect. The final code would look something like:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
        clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
            const client = snapshot.val();
            client.key = snapshot.key;
            setState([...state, client])
         });
        return () => { /*  CLEANUP CODE HERE */ };
    }, []);//An empty array here means  this will run only once.
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, `useEffect` callback is run after every completed render ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)) and you're setting up a new firebase listener each such invocation. So when the Firebase emits the event each of such listeners receives the data snapshot and each of them adds to the state a received value.

Instead you need to set the listener once after component is mounted, you can do so by providing an empty array of the dependencies (`[]`) as a second argument to `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // your code here
}, []) // an empty array as a second argument
```

This will tell React that this effect doesn't have any dependencies so there is no need to run it more than once.

But there is another one important moment. Since you setup a listener then you need to clean it up when you don't need it anymore. This is done by another callback that you should ***return*** in the function that you pass to `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
  clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    const client = snapshot.val();
    client.key = snapshot.key;
    setState([...state, client])
  });
  return () => clientsRef.off('child_added') // unsubscribe on component unmount
}, []);
```

Basically this returned cleanup function will be invoked before every new effect is called and right before a component unmounts ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)) so only this cleanup function should solve your solution by itself, but there's no need to call your effect after every render anyway hence `[]` as a second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Effects, by default, run after every render, and setting state causes a render. [Any effect that updates state *needs* to have a dependency array specified](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect), otherwise you'll just have an infinite update-render-update-render loop.

Also, [remember to clean up any subscriptions that effects create.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) Here, you can do that by returning a function which calls `.off(...)` and removes the listener.

Then, [make sure to use the function form of state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), to make sure the next state *always* relies on the current state, instead of whatever the closure value happened to be when binding the event. [Consider using `useReducer` if your component's state becomes more complex.](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#decoupling-updates-from-actions)

```js
const [clients, setClients] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const clientsRef = firebase.database().ref("clients")

  const handleChildAdded = (snapshot) => {
    const client = snapshot.val()
    client.key = snapshot.key
    setClients(clients => [...clients, client])
  }

  clientsRef.on("child_added", handleChildAdded)
  return () => clientsRef.off('child_added', handleChildAdded)
}, [])
```

Also see:

- [How to fetch data with hooks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/)
- [React Firebase Hooks](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks)
- [A complete guide to `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)